# WPF ListView - Sorting by Nested Properties

Tags: wpf, sorting, listview, properties, nested-properties

I have recently stumbled across an issue where the WPF `ListView` control seems to be restricting the ability to sort its items. Specifically, I am having a great deal of trouble trying to get a `SortDescription` to recognise nested properties (properties of properties).

For straight-forward sorting by propreties, the following line should do the job:

```
listView.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("MyProperty",
    ListSortDirection.Ascending));
```

And indeed it works well for me. However, because the `ItemSource` for my `ListView` is a (strongly-typed) `DataTable`, some of the columns are bound to nested properties of the row (i.e. `Row.OtherTableRow.SubProperty` binding path style) - it's the way ADO.NET DataSets work for hierarchial databases.

What I would like to do is something like this:

```
listView.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("MyProperty.SubProperty",
    ListSortDirection.Ascending));
```

But unfortunately that line throws an `ArgumentException`:

> 'Orders' type does not have property named 'Row.[ID]', so cannot sort data collection.

Strangely enough, I have no problem binding to nested properties. Indeed, the fields display perfectly well in the `ListView`... Nor does adding a `PropertyGroupDescription` to `listView.GroupDescriptions` give me any problems with nested properties - it is only `SortDescriptions`!

Is this but a limitation of WPF/the `ListView` control? Is there any way I'm going to get support as part of the framework, or will I be out of luck there? If I unfortunately am, and this inconsistency is unavoidable, I would much appreciate if someone could suggest a hack or workaround for this scenario of nested properties. I have tried a few ideas already, but all with minimal success.

Note: I realise that an ORM may well solve my problems, but I'm afraid this isn't at all feasible for the current project I'm working on. Simple ADO.NET DataSets will have to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Windows Presentation Foundation Unleased (Adam Nathan), you can cast the default view to a ListCollectionView and set a custom IComparer implementation to its CustomSort property.

Comment: Cheers for that. I may just take a look at that book, if it covers other advanced scenarios well. :)

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to using `SortDescription` is to **provide an `IComparer` object**. `SortDescription` apparently relies on reflection which may be why nested properties won't work well if at all; but the `IComparer` approach has no such limitation, offers much more flexibility, and is claimed to be faster.

The trick in using `IComparer` is that `ICollectionView` doesn't have the needed `.CustomSort` property - however in many (if not all?) cases *you can cast the default view to a* `ListCollectionView` *which exposes the required interface*.

For instance, I have an `ObservableCollection<Something>` whose default view *can* be cast to `ListCollectionView`. I think if this works for `ObservableCollection` its probably good for most scenarios.

Here's an example:

```
ListCollectionView _customerView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(customers);
                                         as ListCollectionView;
_customerView.CustomSort = new CustomerSorter();
```

...

```
public class CustomerSorter : IComparer
{
    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        var custX = (Customer)x;
        var custY = (Customer)y;
        return custX.Name.CompareTo(custY.Name);
    }
}
```

(Source of slightly modified example: https://wpftutorial.net/DataViews.html#sorting)